# What would happen to a charge in uniform magetic field when observed from a moving reference frame?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, charge

Suppose there is a uniform magnetic field everywhere in the space in -z axis direction. And suppose there is a particle at rest with respect to our reference-frame. The arrangement is shown in the figure :

[image]

Now, suppose our reference frames starts moving to the right with a constant velocity. The charged particle would appear to be moving to the left with the same velocity. Now, will there be any magnetic force acting the the charged particle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a magnetic force will appear, for the frame independent quantity is not the magnetic, but the Lorentz force. An electric field will appear as a consequence, so that the particle is subject to the same force in both frames.

Comment: so, the particle will still only move because of the relative motion, because other forces (magnetic and electric) will cancel each other ?

Comment: Yes, no acceleration will appear.

Comment: Thank you, But can you give me much more details ? Like mathematical description ?

Comment: The math comes down to the transformation of the electromagnetic field components under a Lorentz transformation. When you change between inertial frames, those components change according to  certain formulas. Letting the velocity be in the x-direction,  the formulas can be found in table 26.2 from the link bellow (I would write them here but I'm typing from my phone, in which I find them hard to type) Noting that all components except Bz were zero, try to use them to calculate the Lorentz force. 
 http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_26.html

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubts ! It was really helpful.